# Jexcel Formula Calculation Error

Tags: java, excel, formula, jxl, jexcelapi

I have created a worksheet, *out.xls* which had cell D6=D5*2 and D5 set to 1. My issue is that when I plug a value into D5 in jxl, D6 never calculates. D6 simply holds on the value it initially calculated when I plugged in 1 to D5 in excel.

note: I have a much larger programming problem that I am trying to tackle, this is just a very scaled down version to reduce error.

This is my first time ever use Jexcel and I only just learned java this last year, so any help would be appreciated. I spent 6 hours yesterday trying to find an answer on the web, but to no avail.

*the output is attached below the code*
**Code:** (left out the main and imports)

```
        WorkbookSettings custom= new WorkbookSettings();
        custom.setRationalization(true);
        custom.setRefreshAll(true);
        custom.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
        Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("out.xls"),custom); 


        WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), workbook); 

        WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(0); 
        SheetSettings customsheetsettings=new SheetSettings(sheet2);
        customsheetsettings.setAutomaticFormulaCalculation(true); 
        Number number = new Number(3, 4, 3);
        sheet2.addCell(number); 


        copy.write();
        copy.close(); 
        workbook.close();


        Workbook workbook2 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("output.xls")); 
        Sheet sheet=workbook2.getSheet(0);


        System.out.println("D5:"+sheet.getCell(3,4).getContents());
        FormulaCell formula5=(FormulaCell) sheet.getCell(3,5);
        System.out.println("Formula:"+formula5.getFormula());
        System.out.println("D6:"+formula5.getContents()); 

        NumberFormulaCell nfc=(NumberFormulaCell)sheet.getCell(3, 5); 
        System.out.println(nfc.getValue());  
        workbook2.close();
```

**output:**

```
D5:3
Formula:D5*2.0
D6:2
2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

JExcel only allows to read or write Excel files, and give a Java representation of the content of an Excel file. It will not substitute for Excel.

When you add a formula, this formula will be computed, but only in Excel, when you open the generated file in Excel. The cell is not computed by JExcel.

Comment: Alright, thank you. Is there anyway to get the computed results? For the larger project I mentioned I have been trying to take sets of data, insert them into a sheet that does some calculations to them, then put the results elsewhere in the sheet. Is the above project even possible with Jexcel? I could try to use macros, but I would prefer to use java if possible.

Comment: I am afraid not. JExcel does not make any computation. It seems that macros is a better alternative.

Comment: @Teetoo I am modifying an excel but the cells which have formulaes are not getting updates as per the new modified data. What is the alternative? How to use Macros for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else wants to know, POI does that using the FormulaEvaluator class.

Att